# Watson Assistant with Instagram

Tags: instagram, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I'm trying to develope a chatbot to Direct Instagram. Anybody knows if is possible to integrate Watson Assistant (Chatbot) with Direct Instagram?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create chat-bots in Instagram. Whether you can use Watson Assistant or not depends mostly on the Instagram API, that you should check.

But definitely yes! There are nowadays some IG chatbots! You can check some [sources](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-create-a-chat-bot-for-Instagram) to see that!

For example, what this image shows is a spanish IG chatbot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Instagram does not publish APIs for chatbot development, so I don't believe any platforms really support chatbots on Instagram, including Watson.